# How to get maternity insurance on long stay visa in France?

Tags: insurance

I came to France on a passport-talent visa. How to get maternity insurance on long stay visa (Passport talent Researcher) in France immediately?

Comment: Are you working in France, or are you a student?

Comment: I just came here on last week and started my post-doctoral research.

Comment: You should be covered by the social insurance no? You're employed and paying into the system.

Comment: But i contacted them. They said that After 3 months' stay in France, you can apply for it.  but i need to get insurance immediately.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by maternity insurance? Coverage for your healthcare costs related to your pregnancy? Maternity leave? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in France, your employer, or you (depending on the situation), have registered you to the mandatory *Assurance Maladie* Social Security scheme, as soon as you start working, which in turn has assigned you, a 15 digits *NIR* (*Numéro d'inscription au registre INSEE* more commonly known as a *numéro de sécurité sociale* (SSN))

This number certified that you are covered under the social security scheme, which will allow you to access public healthcare and some reimbursement for your health fees (You **need** to also apply for the Social Security Card, the [*Carte Vitale*](https://www.ameli.fr/paris/assure/remboursements/etre-bien-rembourse/carte-vitale#text_64341)).

Now, it isn't full reimbursement for everything, and you may want to get under a *mutuelle complémentaire* (complementary health insurance) for extra coverage.

If you are in the private sector, your employer is required to allow you to subscribe directly (while it will be paid by you) or you can choose it yoursely

Comment: Thanks for the information.
But, I am not getting any funding from France. My own country is sponsoring to me.

Comment: I don't think it matters where the money is coming from. If you are employed in France then a) you are eligible for national health insurance and b) you must pay French taxes and other contributions

Comment: Actually, some specific costs related to pregnancy and all healthcare costs during the last six months of a pregnancy are fully covered by regular health insurance (see https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F164)

Comment: To be honest, getting it all sorted when coming from abroad can be a bit messy (even for a French citizen who already has a NIR). But if you are indeed covered by your work, you can get typically get money back after sorting it out using the old “feuille de soins”.

Comment: https://www.ameli.fr/assure/droits-demarches/europe-international/protection-sociale-france/travailleur-expatriation-france

Comment: Did your employer give you a french social security number ?